# How to use reflect to set the value of a map on a struct?

Tags: go, go-reflect

In Go, how can I use the reflect package to set the value of a `map`?

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
)

type Mapped struct {
    M map[string]string
}
func main() {

    m := map[string]string{"A":"VA", "B": "VB"}
    mv := reflect.ValueOf(m)

    mapped := Mapped{}
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(mapped)

    f := rv.FieldByName("M")
    // f.Set(mv) doesn't work
}
```

The only methods of `Value` I see pertaining to maps are `MapIndex`,`MapKeys`, `MapRange` and `SetMapIndex` (which panics if the `map` is nil).

I can't seem to set the Addr, as maps are not addressable. I'm not sure how to assign `m` above to `mapped.M`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an addressable value for your map by replacing:

```
rv := reflect.ValueOf(mapped)
```

with:

```
rv := reflect.ValueOf(&mapped).Elem()
```

Then you can just call:

```
f := rv.FieldByName("M") 
f.Set(mv)
```

as before.

Taking the value of a pointer and then using indirection to get at the pointed-to value is what makes the difference. Otherwise `reflect.ValueOf` gets a non-addressable copy of your struct, just like any other function would.

Comment: Oh, I missed your edit I think. That definitely helped my comprehension. Thank you!